# what does the delimeter # mean when used in preg_match?

Tags: php

I am a PHP beginner and i am trying to understand what the delimeter # means when used in preg_match. I have searched a lot on Google but i still don´´t understand. can someone tell me what the # means?

please help me

Comment: If `#` is used as delimiter, then it's just that. And since you already found out that's what it is, you should explain how the manual left you confused.

Comment: You are right...i am just bad at english....i had to look up what delimiter means. Now i understand it better :s....sorry my fault for this bad question.

Answer (score 0):

It probably means the same as / the way you are used to see regular expressions is probably

```
 /^foo.*$/
```

but, let's say you want to match a path, and don't want to escape every slash in your pattern, an easy way to do this is to use a different delimiter, so the above expression would become

```
 #^foo.*$#
```

or, a more appropriate example; instead of

```
 /^\/some\/file\/path/
```

you can just do

```
 #^/some/file/path#
```

At least that's how it works in perl, and seeing how the preg_ stands for PERL regular expressions, my money is on that it works the same.

HTH, bovako